# laravel/laravel vs laravel/framework

Tags: php, laravel

I am reviewing Laravel's source code on github and noticed that there is a [laravel/laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) and a [laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework).
They both link to the same documentation on Laravel's website and state that it is a web application framework.

Why two repositories?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[laravel/laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) is for the skeleton application you get when creating a new project. It provides a default structure that's recommended (you're not forced to use it). The repository contains default config files, controllers, routes, etc. As well as code responsible for bootstrapping the application.

It also includes a `composer.json` which defines the actual framework as dependency:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*"
},
```

---

[laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework) is the actual framework source.

As the `readme.md` on the framework repository says:

> Note: This repository contains the core code of the Laravel framework. If you want to build an application using Laravel 5, visit the main [Laravel repository](https://github.com/laravel/laravel).

Comment: So it's like a general foundation/base and the framework is more oriented for MVC?

Comment: The framework is definitely MVC. And the framework repository itself is not really a running application. Technically it's just classes that you can use. Of course it's much more than just a library but it still needs some code that puts things together. That *bootstraps* the application. That's what the other respository is for (besides providing an app structure)

Comment: why we use laravel/laravel while creating new Project?

Answer (score 5):

A [comment](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/a188d62105532fcf2a2839309fb71b862d904612#commitcomment-9975342) that I received on the Laravel repository in relation to this question:

> laravel/laravel is the part of the app that you work with yourself
>   (controllers, config, routes.php, resources, database, etc.) while
>   laravel/framework is the "core" of Laravel, stuff that you don't
>   change.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel/Laravel is the application template/skeleton, and is the starting point for Laravel 4 apps.
Laravel/Framework is the kernal, which contains the actual framework components itself, and is downloaded by Composer into your application template/skeleton.